# How to define a custom order in ORDER BY clause?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE article.category IN (1, 57, 67, 78)
ORDER BY article.category ASC
```

Instead of ordering it ascending, I would like to order it like:

```
ORDER BY article.category (1, 67, 78, 57)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the FIELD function:-

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE article.category IN (1, 57, 67, 78)
ORDER BY FIELD(article.category, 1, 67, 78, 57)
```

EDIT - If not found it will return 0, so if you want 2 values sorted first then possibly just have those 2 in the function but reversed and sort descending.

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE article.category IN (1, 57, 67, 78)
ORDER BY FIELD(article.category, 67, 1) DESC
```

This will put category of 1 first, category 67 afterwards, followed by any others

Comment: Can I also define two categories instead of all? For example I want category 1 and 67 to come first. The rest of the order doesn't matter

Comment: You can, I have edited the answer with a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the string function FIELD():

```
ORDER BY FIELD(article.category, 1, 67, 78, 57)
```

(even if category is a number, it will be automatically casted to a string).

Otherwise to define any custom order you could just use CASE WHEN, for example:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN article.category IN (1, 67) THEN 1
    WHEN article.category IN (78, 57) THEN 2
  ELSE 3 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method to achieve that is to use `JOIN` and subquery with column that indicates order:

```
SELECT a.*          -- if join is not on `UNIQUE/PK` column DISTINCT may be required
FROM articles a
JOIN (SELECT 1 AS ord, 1 AS category
      UNION ALL SELECT 2, 57
      UNION ALL SELECT 3, 67
      UNION ALL SELECT 4, 78) AS sub
  ON a.category = sub.category
ORDER BY sub.ord ASC
```