# Order by clause ignored in crystal user defined command

Tags: plsql, crystal-reports, listagg

I am using the below query as a user defined command command in crystal 2013. It returns and orders properly in sql developer but when I add it to my report the fields are either returned twice and/or in the wrong order. It should return rows based on ID ascending e.g. 39-40-41-42. But returns 39-41-40-42... Or 3939-4141-4040-4242. So there seems to be a pattern..

```
select ad.arinvt_id,
ud.parent_id, listagg(ud.cuser, '') within group (order by ud.parent_id) as sfdt, 
listagg(ud.ud_cols_id, '') within group (order by ud.ud_cols_id) as uci
from arinvoice_detail ad
left join ud_data ud
on ad.arinvt_id = ud.parent_id
where ad.arinvt_id = ud.parent_id
and ud.ud_cols_id in (39, 40, 41, 42)
group by ad.arinvt_id, ud.parent_id
```

I haven't been able to find much, what I have found is on different platforms. Any help is much appreciated!

I saw this:
[How to define a custom order in ORDER BY clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158573/how-to-define-a-custom-order-in-order-by-clause)
and tried to change to

```
(order by field(xyz))
```

but crystal wouldn't take that.

Comment: I couldn't understand your query what is within group stands for in query

Comment: @Siva it is used to order the listagg items. That seems to be the part that crystal is taking issue with..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was linking the table twice. Once in the command, again in crystal. Not sure why it did the duplication some times and not others, or why the order was skewed.. but the below command works so far.

```
select
ud.parent_id, 
listagg(ud.cuser, '') within group (order by ud.ud_cols_id) as sfdt
from ud_data ud
where ud.ud_cols_id in (39, 40, 41, 42)
group by ud.parent_id
```